# We report something or report on / about something?

Tags: prepositions

Does the verb 'report' needs a preposition in the following context?  I have many choices and I'm not sure what's natural.

> I found there an error and I want to report them **on / about** it.
>
> I found there an error and I want to report **on** (or about)  it to them.
>
> I found there an error and I want to report it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Elizabeth suggests, your sentences start incorrectly. Normally we'd just say:

> I found an error

But if you really want to use "there":

> I found an error there
>
> I found there's an error (I found [that] there is an error)

For the second part, you can just say:

> I want to report it to them

There is no need for **on** or **about**, as the verb **report** can be used with an object.

To combine these suggestions, I would say:

> I found an error, and I want to report it to them.

When you **report on** something, that's normally longer-term. For example, a months-long investigation might report on something.

Comment: I want to denote where I found the error.  Can I not use the word 'there'? (i.e. I found it there)

Comment: @JudiciousAllure Please see the second part of my answer

Comment: Thank you. I did,  but still not understood the answer.

Comment: Just use the recommended language from the second part, "I found an error there." This should give you, "I found an error there, and I want to report it to them."